# Know if there are some elements on other element in SVG?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to simulate movement of elements in SVG
i have some circles and i need to get event when one circle is touching 
other Circle , or starting to hide it.
Is there an attribute or function ?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in function for this.  You will have to detect it yourself.